# Can someone explain this error in `scan()`?

Tags: r, list, file

Can you please help me to understand this error in `scan()`.

I believe the error is in `what=list(.)`   If so, can someone help clarify?

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to decode what you are asking!

Comment: Why all the down votes?  There is a screen shot of an error, and the question is asking what is wrong with the line of code indicated in the error.

Comment: @Ricardo, screen shots are only a bit helpful.  Think of it like this.  lat's say your car was not working and you opened the hood and took a picture.  Do you think the mechanic will be happier if you bring the car to him or the picture?  You generally can't diagnose a picture.  Now reproducible examples, they are testable.  You can see the error, run things like `str` `traceback` `browser` etc and figure things out.  If nothing else even if a picture does tell the story it puts the onus of the code production on the person helping rather than the poster. Oh and I don't speak Spanish either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is expecting the list to contain ***only*** real numbers, but instead the list contains real numbers (`0`) and strings (`""`).

If you would like to give an empty value for a number, instead of `""` try using `NA`.   So the line would be

```
 what=list(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0)
```